# PHP session error on creating new user

Tags: php, session, authentication

I'm creating a service with php/mysql where the user has to register before using it.

1. I've got an **index.php** file where you can register and login. it has this php session check in the top of the document `

   ```
    <?php
       session_start();
       if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) 
       {
          header("location: foosball/");
          exit();
       }
       session_write_close();  
    ?>
   ```
2. Then I have the **register.php** file which I use when a new user tries to register. I'm starting a new session here, but this session is not working, when I try to access the restricted area **foosball/index.php**

   ```
   session_start();
   session_regenerate_id();
   setcookie(session_name('Foosball'),session_id(),time()+56*7*24*60*60);
   $_SESSION['id'] = $mysqli->insert_id;
   $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;
   $_SESSION['lastname'] = $lastname;
   $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
   $_SESSION['company'] = $company;
   $_SESSION['state'] = $state;
   session_write_close();
   header('Location: foosball/');
   ```
3. The **foosball/index.php** file also has the session check in the top.

   ```
   <?php
     session_start();

     if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
       header("location: ../index.php");
       exit();
      }
   ?>
   ```

The problem is, that when I register and adds the user data to the database I also want to set a session, and continue to the foosball/index.php area. But the session is not valid, cause the session check on the foosball/index.php page returns the user to the index.php page. BUT, when I login afterwards with my login script and set a new session, everything works as intended. I really hope you guys can help me.

Thanks
Kasper

Comment: have you tryed to print every $_SESSION to see it? comment the `//header('location: foosball/')` an see your sessions id whit a `var_dump()`

Comment: try putting `exit();` after `header('Location: foosball/');` in register.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script does not work because the function you use to insert an id in the database does not return anything so `$_SESSION['id']` will be always unset you need to modify your insert_id function in order to return something for example the id you're trying to insert, and call it from your script passing the id you want to add into the DB.

EXAMPLE:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $mysqlObject->insert_id(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
```

FUNCTION :

```
function insert_id($id){
    //Insert values is db
    //...
    return $id; //then return something to put into $_SESSION['id']
}
```